# Not a Function After First Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS Function that looks like this:

```
$(function() {
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function (event) {
   $("dd.active").find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
   $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("slow");

   var current = event.currentTarget
   if (current.hasClass('active')) {
      current.removeClass('active');
   } 
})
});
```

The first part works fine, the second part (starting with `var current =`) works the first time then jQuery throws an error:

```
TypeError: current.hasClass is not a function
   if (current.hasClass('active')) {
```

How do I solve this issue?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KH9LP/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap current reference in jQuery object

```
   var current = $(event.currentTarget);
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KH9LP/2/)

Comment: To add to this: `event.currentTarget` is a reference to a DOM element. the `hasClass()` and `removeClass()` methods are jQuery functions, so you must turn that DOM element into a jQuery object as Sarath wrote out.